# If $\lim_{x\to 1 }\frac{f(x)-8}{x-1} = 10.$ Find $\lim_{x\to 1 }f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

If $$\lim_{x\to 1 }\frac{f(x)-8}{x-1} = 10.$$ Find  $$\lim_{x\to 1 }f(x)$$

<s>I am trying to solve this by having $(x-1)$ be a factor of $f(x) - 8$ but can't solve for $f(x)$</s>

Edit: Figured out the solution:

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 1 }f(x)-8 = \lim_{x\to 1 }\frac{f(x)-8}{x-1}\cdot(x-1) = \lim_{x\to 1 }\frac{f(x)-8}{x-1} \cdot \Big(\lim_{x\to 1 }x-1\Big) = 10\cdot 0 = 0 $$

$$\lim_{x\to 1 }f(x) - \lim_{x\to 1 }8 = 0$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1 }f(x) - 8 = 0$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1 }f(x) = 8$$

Comment: I took the liberty to slightly edit the formatting. If you do not like it, do not hesitate to roll it back.